# Taking input and working with numbers in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, 8085

I'm working with Emulator 8085A and I am trying to do an exercise, but I can't find any information or examples of taking input and working with it.

I have to make an assembly program for MIPS processors which reads 50 numbers from keyboard. We call a procedure for each number to check if it can be divided by 5, and if it can be, then we call another procedure to sum all numbers which are NOT divided by 5 and then print the sum.

Any help about this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not entirely clear why you're talking about using an 8085 (x86 family) emulator for a MIPS assignment. They're unrelated CPU architectures.

Comment: @AndrewMedico Because I was given it by the teacher. 8085A Emulator is what it is called. Looks like this: http://i.gyazo.com/3466dd066ec13965dfce09f8f5618440.png

Comment: Then what does MIPS have to do with the question? If you're using an 8085 emulator you should write 8085 assembly, not MIPS assembly.

Comment: @Michael the task says MIPS assembly.

Comment: If you're really supposed to write MIPS assembly you need something that can run MIPS code, like SPIM or MARS. An assignment where you're given an 8085 emulator and being told to write MIPS assembly  makes no sense. That's kind of like being given a copy of Turbo Pascal to solve a Java assignment. I suggest that you talk to your teacher and ask him/her for clarification.

Comment: @Michael I did ask, and it seems to be an optional task, for those who want to do MIPS code. I'm interested to the solution of this task, but I have no MIPS experience.